# Error: Cannot find module 'xmldom'

Tags: node.js, xmldom

I am getting this error, i have installed xmldom using

`npm install xmldom`

, into the directory

`C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs_10.35\node_modules\npm\node_modules`.

i checked the package.json inside xmldom, it is intact and when i run my script with this line

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
```

I get the error.

I searched a lot to resolve this issue, I verified all the suggestions but none worked. In some thread someone suggested to install wherever app.js file is present, but I could not find that in my nodejs installation directory.

Comment: can u provide ur package.json file and app.js file's content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to `npm install xmldom` in the directory (or in a parent directory) of the directory where your script resides that does the `require(xmldom)` and not where node is installed

Answer (score 1):

As per latest changes made in library `npm install xmldom` is no longer supported. We should use `npm i @xmldom/xmldom`

> **Since version 0.7.0 this package is published to npm as @xmldom/xmldom and no longer as xmldom, because we are no longer able to publish xmldom.**

[NPM documentation available here for more details](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@xmldom/xmldom)